# How to change view date dynamically (which is filter event by date time)

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler, kendo-datepicker

I Want to filter event by date but date is pass by normal input type="text" not kendo default datepicker.And display passing date in kendo schduler header But cant not change view date.This is my code.........

```
 $scope.searchEventByDate = function (item) {
    var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
    scheduler.view().startDate(item.StartDate);
    scheduler.view().endDate(item.EndDate);
    scheduler.view(("day"));
    $scope.scheduler.dataSource.read();       
};
```

This is my filter param

```
 parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                var popupheight = $(window).height() - 180 + 'px';
                $scope.popupWraperForTryout = popupheight;
                var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
                if (searchCount != 0) {
                    if (operation === "read") {
                        return {
                            filterByPersonalEvent: $scope._filterParamObj.filterBypersonal,
                            filterBySignUpRequired: $scope._filterParamObj.filterBySingupRequired,
                            filterByPaidOrFree: $scope._filterParamObj.filterByPaid,
                            filterByEventStatus: $scope._filterParamObj.eventStatusId,
                            filterByEventType: $scope._filterParamObj.eventTypeId,
                            selectedTeam: $scope._filterParamObj.seasonTeamId,
                            filterByStartDate: scheduler.view().startDate(),
                            filterByEndDate: scheduler.view().endDate(),
                            OrgId: _orgId,
                            UserTimezone: global.userTimezoneOffset
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
```

I am so tired.This code is not change in view date.Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues here - the day view shows just one day; you can't set startDate and endDate - just date.

```
$scope.searchEventByDate = function (item) {
  var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
  //scheduler.view().startDate(item.StartDate);
  //scheduler.view().endDate(item.EndDate);
  scheduler.view("day");
  // item.StartDate should be Date object - like scheduler.date(new Date("2013/6/6"));
  scheduler.date(item.StartDate);
  $scope.scheduler.dataSource.read();       
};
```

If you need to set some explicit date range to filter - you can do it, but still you can't show more than just one day in day view.

```
$scope.searchEventByDate = function (item) {
  var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
  scheduler._myFilterStartDate = item.StartDate;
  scheduler._myFilterEndDate = item.EndDate;
  scheduler.view("day");
  scheduler.date(item.StartDate);
  $scope.scheduler.dataSource.read();       
};
```

And in parameter map:

```
...
return {
  filterByStartDate: scheduler.view().startDate(),
  filterByEndDate: scheduler.view().endDate(),
  myFilterStartDate: scheduler._myFilterStartDate,
  myFilterEndDate: scheduler._myFilterEndDate,
  OrgId: _orgId,
  UserTimezone: global.userTimezoneOffset
};
...
```